# Multiple connected lists UX design

Tags: lists, booking

I am designing a Web Application administrator screen and require these elements and tasks on a single page. Not sure how to design this using panels or any other kind of UX widget. The user's journey can start either viewing things or individuals but somehow both need to come together.

List of searchable individuals

List of searchable things

List of an individual's current things

Assign a new thing to an individual

Assign a new thing to multiple individuals

Answer (score 1):

[image: THINGS AND INDIVIDUALS]

Could this be your solution? You would be able to filter for individuals in the drop down by typing their names. I created a toggle, just to keep mobile in mind, but I think you could benefit from having a it broken out as a list on larger screens. Not sure what other features you will have 
...

Comment: This does look interesting and a step in the right direction for us. I think the important element of an individual's list of things is still missing.